# RSA 2048 key generation and secure storage in Android

Tags: android, encryption, aes, rsa

Hi what are the various RSA 2048 key generation and secure storage methods in Android.

I have an app where I need to generate pubic-private key pair in Android and sent public key to server.The private key must be securely stored at client side.How can I ensure that the private key is securely stored ? Is there any reliable key storage mechanism available in 
android ?

I've thought of using AES to encrypt private is it a good method?Should I be using a static key in source code itself or based on some user's input ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a Key Store in your app for secure key storage. Storing keys in you source is the 'anti secure' way. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html

Comment: Thank you.What sort of protection does keystore offer?

Comment: This Android article will do a better job then i could explaining how to use  a keystore in your app: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html